# how to find Hypernym relation from wordnet using Sparql query?

Tags: sparql, wordnet

How to find Hypernym relation from wordnet using Sparql query?
 I can find easily hyponym relation but i can't able to find hypernym relation.

Following example for hyponym relation.

```
"SELECT ?hypo "
+ "WHERE {"
                    + "  wn20instances:synset-tank-noun-1 wn20schema:hyponymOf*  ?hypo . " 
                    + "}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Would simply reversing the relationship work for you?

Reverse the sense of the property:

```
{ wn20instances:synset-tank-noun-1 (^wn20schema:hyponymOf)* ?hyper  . }
```

or (reverse the subject/object)

```
{ ?hyper wn20schema:hyponymOf* wn20instances:synset-tank-noun-1 . }
```

Comment: how i can get all noun senses from this query(for example tank)?